# Git removed last commits after checkout

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I have a problem. I commited many changes in Android Studio. After this I noticed that this wasn't my master branch. And I wanted to look something in my master branch. So I checked out my master branch (it was like 4 commits behind) and now every commit after master is gone. I can't find them anymore. Git should have the versions somewhere, right? How can I get this back?

I hope for help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check all the branches you have using `git branch` and see if you have committed your changes to a different branch by checking out each branch `git checkout {branchname}`.

If you find your commits, you can merge the branches `git merge master {branchname}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you made the commits, they will be in [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). You can then create a branch pointing at the last commit that you wanted to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you just checkout to master branch and don’t make any changes. You can find the version you made by `git reflog`, and the commit id should be in `HEAD@{1}`.

To **get all the changes back to master**, you can use

```
git checkout -b temp <commit id HEAD@{1} point>
git rebase --onto master <start commit id> temp
```

Or if you **only want to get the last version you made to master**, just use

```
git cherry-pick <commit id HEAD@{1} point>
```